# Drag and Drop List- method 'call' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a drag and drop list using `flutter_list_drag_and_drop 0.1.6`. I've looked for examples of how to implement it, but there aren't any out yet for this specifically, so much of it has been trial and error. Anyway, when I run the app, it gives me an error when trying to drag one of the MyDraggables for the list view. It's says "Exception caught by gesture", "The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The method 'call' was called on null," "Receiver: null", "Tried calling: call(Instance of 'Offset').

I've tried debugging but can not locate where exactly this is crashing. The feedback for the draggable widget is appearing, but stays stuck in place.

````
```
       Widget _buildDragDrop(double _screenHeight, double _screenWidth){
        return DragAndDropList(_nonDelList.getList(),
          canBeDraggedTo: (int i, int j) {
            print("drag to");
            // _nonDelList.changePos(_nonDelList.getTaskAt(i), j);
            return true;
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, Task _t1) {
            print('Entered Item Builder');
            return _buildTask(_t1, _screenHeight, _screenWidth);
          },
          onDragFinish: (int i, int j){
            print('Drag finished');
             _nonDelList.changePos(_nonDelList.getTaskAt(i), j);
            print('Drag finished 2');
          },
          dragElevation: 1.5,
        );
      }

       Widget _buildTask(Task _t, double _screenHeight, double 
         _screenWidth){
        final bool alreadyCompleted = !(_t.getPressed());
           return new MyDraggable(
             child: new ListTile(
               title: new Text(_t.getEntry()),
               trailing: new Icon(
                 alreadyCompleted ? Icons.check_box : 
                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                 color: alreadyCompleted ? _t.getColor() : Colors.black,
               ),
               subtitle: new Text(_t.getDescription()),
             ),
             onDragStarted: (){
               print('Started Drag');
             },
             onMyDraggableCanceled: (Velocity v, Offset o){
               print('Drag Canceled');
             },
             feedback: Material(
               shape: CircleBorder(),
               child: new InkResponse(
                 child: Container(
                   width: _screenWidth / 15.0,
                   height: _screenWidth / 15.0,
                   color: Colors.red,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           );
         }
```
````

I would expect the list tile to drag and drop in place.  The only thing that is happening however, is my feedback is appearing at the top left of the list tile when I start the drag, and then this error is immediately spit out. Also, 'Started Drag' and 'Drag Canceled' are not print out, the only thing that is printing is 'Entered Item Builder.'

I welcome and appreciate all help!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT (Stacktrace)

```
I/flutter ( 2974): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2974): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 2974): The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 2974): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 2974): Tried calling: call(Instance of 'Offset')
I/flutter ( 2974):
I/flutter ( 2974): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 2974): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 2974): #1      DragAvatar.updateDrag
package:flutter_list_drag_and_drop/my_draggable.dart:547
I/flutter ( 2974): #2      new DragAvatar
package:flutter_list_drag_and_drop/my_draggable.dart:498
I/flutter ( 2974): #3      MyDraggableState._startDrag
package:flutter_list_drag_and_drop/my_draggable.dart:328
I/flutter ( 2974): #4      MultiDragGestureRecognizer._startDrag.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:263
I/flutter ( 2974): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:120
I/flutter ( 2974): #6      MultiDragGestureRecognizer._startDrag 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:263
I/flutter ( 2974): #7      MultiDragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:253
I/flutter ( 2974): #8      _ImmediatePointerState.accepted 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:315
I/flutter ( 2974): #9      MultiDragGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:253
I/flutter ( 2974): #10     GestureArenaManager._resolveInFavorOf 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:263
I/flutter ( 2974): #11     GestureArenaManager._resolve 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:222
I/flutter ( 2974): #12     GestureArenaEntry.resolve 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:52
I/flutter ( 2974): #13     MultiDragPointerState.resolve 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:62
I/flutter ( 2974): #14     _ImmediatePointerState.checkForResolutionAfterMove 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:310
I/flutter ( 2974): #15     MultiDragPointerState._move 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:81
I/flutter ( 2974): #16     MultiDragGestureRecognizer._handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/multidrag.dart:227
I/flutter ( 2974): #17     PointerRouter._dispatch 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73
I/flutter ( 2974): #18     PointerRouter.route 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101
I/flutter ( 2974): #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:214
I/flutter ( 2974): #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:192
I/flutter ( 2974): #21     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:149
I/flutter ( 2974): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
I/flutter ( 2974): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:85
I/flutter ( 2974): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10)
I/flutter ( 2974): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)
I/flutter ( 2974): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 2974):
I/flutter ( 2974): Handler: onStart
I/flutter ( 2974): Recognizer:
I/flutter ( 2974):   ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer#774eb
```

Comment: I have this feeling the problem lies in `MyDraggable`. Can you try [this](https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_list_drag_and_drop/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says:

```
I/flutter ( 2974): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 2974): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 2974): #1      DragAvatar.updateDrag
package:flutter_list_drag_and_drop/my_draggable.dart:547
```

Okay, so the null pointer exception occurred there.  Let's take a look at [the code](https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_list_drag_and_drop/blob/e83da36e82cfff896f9805499a0e17c33775957e/lib/my_draggable.dart#L547):

```
onMove(globalPosition);
```

That fits the error message, which was:

```
I/flutter ( 2974): Tried calling: call(Instance of 'Offset')
```

So `globalPosition` is likely an `Offset`, and `onMove` must be an object.  Let's search in the code where `onMove` was supposed to be set:

```
DragAvatar({
    @required this.overlayState,
    ...
    this.onMove,
```

([line 491](https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_list_drag_and_drop/blob/e83da36e82cfff896f9805499a0e17c33775957e/lib/my_draggable.dart#L491))

which (omitting some steps) appears to be obtained from:

```
 const MyDraggable({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.feedback,
    ...
    this.onMove
```

([line 101](https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_list_drag_and_drop/blob/e83da36e82cfff896f9805499a0e17c33775957e/lib/my_draggable.dart#L101))

I don't see anywhere else where `onMove` is otherwise set.  It looks like there's probably a bug that `DragAvatar.updateDrag` unconditionally calls `onMove`, that `onMove` isn't marked `@required` initially, or that `onMove` isn't initialized to some default.

At any rate, try supplying an `onMove` callback when constructing `MyDraggable`.

(Alternatively, perhaps consider using the official [ReorderableListView class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html), which the [flutter_list_drag_and_drop](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_list_drag_and_drop) package page even refers to.)

Comment: Thanks so much, adding the onMove stopped the error!